# If statement in C always returning false

Tags: c, if-statement, strcmp, c-strings

I am fairly new to C, so am not overly familiar with it's syntax, however I have debugged my code and researched for the correct syntax, and it seems to be correct, I have also changed the scope of the variables to see if this was causing the error.

The if statement should compare two variables, which both hold strings, I have even printed both the variables out to ensure they are the same, however it is still skipping straight to the else section of the if statement. Can anyone give me any pointers on why it will not run the if statement, it just skips straight to 'incorrect'.

The `correctWord` variable is defined at a different section in the code.

Find full code [here](http://codepad.org/EQoXktaS).

**-UPDATE-**

I have now updated the syntax of the code, however it is still returning false.

[image: Output screen]

```
char correctWord[20];

void userGuess(){
    char userWordGuess[20];

    printf("Anagram: ");
    printf(anagramWord);
    printf("Your Guess: ");
    scanf("%s",userWordGuess); //Reads in user input

    printf(correctWord);
    printf(userWordGuess);

    if(strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord) == 0){
        printf("Congratulations, you guessed correctly!");
    }else{
        printf("Incorrect, try again or skip this question");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare strings.

Comment: You don't set the value of correctWord.     The comparison should be if (strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord)==0) {...

Comment: correctWord and userWordGuess are pointers! they represent the address where are the two 20 bytes strings you declared! Because you want to compare strings, the soluction is as CoreyStup says you!

Comment: Why the down votes? The question is well expressed, the issue is clear, the relevant code is displayed and well-formatted.

Comment: I do not understand the down votes either, I have tried to be very fair and clear with the question, still can't get it to work though http://codepad.org/EQoXktaS

Comment: @axiac Likely because of the minimal research effort. This is such a FAQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *cannot* compare strings in C using `==`, because this compares the **addresses** of the strings, not the contents of the string. (which you certainly don't require, and obviously, the addresses of the two strings are not equal too.)

C has a pretty nice function for it : [`strcmp()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) which returns `0` if both the strings are equal.

Try using this in your `if` condition:

```
if (!strcmp(userWordGuess,correctWord))
{
     //Yay! Strings are equal. Do what you want to here.
}
```

Be sure to `#include <string.h>` before using `strcmp()`.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I have tried this but it is still returning false, find full code here http://codepad.org/EQoXktaS

Comment: @TobyCannon Probably you aren't reading the user input correctly. You'll need to discard line feed characters from stdin.

Answer (score 4):

In C, you can't compare strings using `==`. You will end up comparing the addresses of the strings, which is not the same.

You need to call the `strmcp()` function, which will return `0` if its arguments (two strings) are equal.

So the code should be `if(strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord) == 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, tried implementing this and it's still returning false all of the time?

Comment: @TobyCannon The explanation is in your screenshot. One of your strings (the one read from a file using `fgets()`) ends in a newline, the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing addresses of different arrays, which will always be unequal.

You need to use `strcmp` or some other strings library function to compare strings character by character.

Answer (score 2):

`userWordGuess == correctWord` will compare the pointers (i.e. the locations in memory of the arrays), which are probably not equal.

For string comparision in C, use `strcmp` (or `strncmp`):

```
if (!strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord)){
    /*Strings are equal*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 if(strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord) == 0) // strings are equal
 {
      printf("Congratulations, you guessed correctly!");
 }
 else  // not equal
 {
      printf("Incorrect, try again or skip this question");
 }
```

if both string are equal than `if` condition will run. otherwise it wil run `else`

Answer (score 1):

The strings are not first-class citizens in the `C` language. The strings are represented as either arrays of characters or pointers to such arrays.

In both cases, the variable you use to access the string is a synonym for the address in memory of the first character of the string.

What you compare with `userWordGuess == correctWord` is not the strings but their addresses in memory. Since `userWordGuess` and `correctWord` are two different arrays of characters, their addresses in memory are always different and their comparison will always produce `FALSE`.

In order to compare the actual string values you have to use the standard function [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) or one of its variants (find them at the bottom of the documentation page).

Change in the code:

```
/** Need to include the header that declares the strcmp() function */
#include <string.h>

char correctWord[20];

void userGuess(){
    char userWordGuess[20];

    /** stripped some lines here ... */

    /** compare the strings, not their addresses in memory */
    if (strcmp(userWordGuess, correctWord) == 0) {

    /** the rest of your code */
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is comparing two pointers. userWordGuess and correctWord point each to the beginning of an array of characters (which is what you defined at the beginning of your example code).

So if you want to compare the two arrays of chars you can use the [strcmp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) function defined in string.h

It is important that you learn the relation between arrays and pointers. Pointer arithmetic is as well important here. Check this out: [Arrays, Pointers, Pointer Arithmetic](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/section2.1.3.html)